# Is my answer correct? (And what's the name of the rule?)$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(n+3\right)!-n!}{n\left(n+2\right)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Want to know if I solved this problem correctly:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(n+3\right)!-n!}{n\left(n+2\right)!} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 \cdot 2 \ldots(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) - 1 \cdot 2 \ldots(n-1)n}{(1 \cdot 2 \ldots(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2))\cdot n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1 \cdot 2 \ldots(n-1) n)\cdot((n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-1)}{(1 \cdot 2 \ldots(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2))\cdot n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdot n} = \frac{1}{1}=1$$ 
The answer is 1 because we've got $n^3$ in numerator and $n^3 $ in denominator, and the constants are both equals 1 so the limit can be calculated as $\frac{1}{1}$. (Sorry I don't remember that rule. Could you remain me please?)

Comment: The answer below is correct, but you may be thinking of L'Hopital's rule (which is not the technique the answer applied, but a different way to solve the problem)

Comment: I would have factored $n!$ out of the nemerator and denominator, just for notational convenience. Yes, after cancellation, you're left with the quotient of two cubics with leading coefficient 1, so your limit should be 1. Your argument looks OK. I don't think there's a name for the rule. You are taking the limit at infinity of a rational function; that's the only terminology that I have ever used.

Comment: @Tyler Yes, L'Hopital's rule is nice but I'm only first-year student and I haven't covered this rule yet. I'll learn it later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can more easily write the expression (cancelling as much as possible) as $$\frac {n+3}n-\frac 1{n(n+1)(n+2)}=1+\frac 3n-\frac 1{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Then the limit is very easy to see.

Answer (score 2):

If $m=n$, and $a_n,b_m\neq 0$, then you can say the following:$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0}{b_mx^m+\cdots+b_0}=\frac{a_n}{b_m}.$$
To prove this, you can factor out the $x$ terms from the numerator and denominator like so: $$\frac{a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0}{b_mx^m+\cdots+b_0}=\frac{x^n}{x^m}\cdot\frac{a_n+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}}{b_m+\cdots+\frac{b_0}{x^m}}.$$
Now since $n = m$, $x^n/x^m=1$, the limit becomes $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{a_n+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}}{b_m+\cdots+\frac{b_0}{x^m}} =\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty}a_n+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}}{\lim_{x \to \infty}b_m+\cdots+\frac{b_0}{x^m}}=\frac{a_n}{b_m}.$$
since all the terms with an $x$ in the denominator go to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. You can also use a similar technique to show that if $m > n$ then the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thanks. And does it rule have a name?

Comment: As Chris Leary said, there probably isn't one, but if you say something like "limit at infinity of a rational function" people will understand your meaning.